# How to display nested objects and or arrays in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, ngfor

I am getting json data from the back-end(api). And i want to display this with ngFor. I got an error message like: **"Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'"** from the console.

later I tried this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'mapToIterable'
})
export class MapToIterable implements PipeTransform{
    transform(map: {}, args: any[] = null): any {
        if (!map)
            return null;
        return Object.keys(map)
            .map((key) => ({ 'key': key, 'value': map[key] }));
    }
}
```

and then in my view:

```
 <li *ngFor="let detail of getEventDetails | mapToIterable">
            Creator Email: {{detail.creator.email}}
     </li>
```

this time i didn't get an error but there is no display values of `{{detail.creator.email}}`

Data from back-end

```
 {
        "banner_image": null, 
        "categories": [], 
        "creator": {
            "email": "email@email.com", 
            "first_name": "Prince", 
            "gender": true, 
            "id": 15, 
            "last_name": "Odame", 
            "subscribed_categories": [], 
            "watchlist": []
        }, 
        "creator_id": 15, 
        "description": "Learn how to install solar panels in 3 days and make real money all your lifetime", 
        "faqs": [], 
        "id": 6, 
        "is_verified": true, 
        "max_tickets_per_user": 1, 
        "shows": [
            {
                "address": "Engineering Auditorium, College of Engineering, KNUST, Kumasi", 
                "city": "Kumasi", 
                "country": "Ghana", 
                "end_time": "2016-08-03T14:30:00+00:00", 
                "event_id": 6, 
                "id": 5, 
                "is_online": false, 
                "start_time": "2016-08-01T08:30:00+00:00", 
                "state": "Ashanti", 
                "ticket_types": [], 
                "venue": "Engineering Auditorium"
            }
        ], 
        "tags": [], 
        "title": "Solar Panels Installation Workshop"
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This won't work like that. Read the code of the pipe - you now have key/value objects in an array. Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wuVNDpVErNNiXlAn8GJk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @rinukkusu it works for me but is there a way to values of the sub arrays

Comment: Not with `*ngFor`. Without it you can just use `{{getEventDetails.creator.email}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just want to do this:

```html
<li>Creator Email: {{getEventDetails.creator.email}}</li>
```

And for the arrays:

```html
<li *ngFor="let show of getEventDetails?.shows">
   Show ID: {{show.id}}
</li>
```